# writing file using cat with here-document

Tags: bash, unix, cat

```
$ cat > out.txt <<EOF
> Hello world
> EOF
$
```

How do I do this in single statement?
Somethig like 'echo' in following statement

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do echo "Hello world" > out_$i.txt; done
```

Comment: That *is* a single statement; do you mean on one line?

Comment: Why do you need to do it in a single line?

Comment: @chepner yes. I mean one line.

Comment: @slartidan just out of curiosity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a here-string, which is a shortcut for short here documents in `bash`.

```
cat <<< "Hello world" > out.txt
```